# How to fix AWS security ALAS-2019-1149?

Tags: aws

I need to investigate for the security hole ALAS-2019-1149(https://alas.aws.amazon.com/ALAS-2019-1149.html) which is report ed by AWS.
I saw in the session "Issue Correction"
Run yum update kernel to update your system.
I understood that I only update the kernel without rebooting the target server

I just updated the kernel with that command line

```
[root@ip-10-0-10-67 ~]# uname -r
4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64
[root@ip-10-0-10-67 ~]# yum update kernel
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                                              | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                                           | 2.5 kB     00:00
stns/x86_64                                                                                                                                                   | 2.5 kB     00:00
stns/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                        | 9.0 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:4.14.97-74.72.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=====================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                               Arch                                  Version                                               Repository                                   Size
=====================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 kernel                                x86_64                                4.14.97-74.72.amzn1                                   amzn-updates                                 21 M

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 21 M
Installed size: 90 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
kernel-4.14.97-74.72.amzn1.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                         |  21 MB     00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : kernel-4.14.97-74.72.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                                                                 1/1
  Verifying  : kernel-4.14.97-74.72.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                                                                 1/1

Installed:
  kernel.x86_64 0:4.14.97-74.72.amzn1
```

But when I checked kernel again, don't have nay changing update in kernel

```
[root@ip-10-0-10-67 ~]# uname -r
4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64
```

But I wonder how to verify the updating?

Thank in advance!

Comment: `uname -r` reports the currently running kernel. You cannot replace the underlying kernel while keeping the system on top of the kernel running (there are things like kpatch and similar which hot-patch an existing running kernel, but that's not what you are doing here). Thus, in order to run the new kernel you need to reboot the specific system.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, But AWS said that I only update the kernel and don't need to reboot  server. Is it ok to fix the hole?

Comment: It is not enough to just install some fixed software but you have to stop running the vulnerable version and use the fixed one. This is true for the kernel too, i.e. a reboot is needed.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich. What do you think about that information https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/no-reboot-kernel-patching-and-why-you-should-care. From kernel-4 we don't need to reboot server for updating patch security holes

Comment: To cite myself: *"there are things like kpatch and similar which hot-patch an existing running kernel, but that's not what you are doing here"*. kpatch and similar is exactly what this article is about and it does not apply to what you do: you install a new kernel and don't hot-patch an existing one.